# Pagnation not updating target - Asp.Net Core using Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, pagination, asp.net-core

I hope this is straight forward! I have a partial which loads just fine, it uses ajax to apply filters / sorting which works fine. However the pagination links send the correct url, and the response is the desired page, only it doesn't actually update/replace whats there.
Parent View:

```
    @model Sakura.AspNetCore.IPagedList<YaCu_2017.Models.Review>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Review Dashboard";
@using YaCu_2017.Controllers;

}
<p class="green-text">@ViewBag.StatusMessage</p>
<p class="red-text">@ViewBag.ErrorMessage</p>

<h2>Our Product Reviews</h2>
<div class="row">
<div class="col s2">

    <h5>Filter by Product:</h5>

    <form method="get">
        @{
            var product = ReviewController.GetProductListIncId();
            var productCount = ReviewController.GetProductCountList();
            ViewBag.ProductList = product;
            ViewBag.ProductCount = productCount;
        }
        <select asp-items="@ViewBag.ProductList" id="searchProduct" 
class="dropdown-button btn"></select>
        <h5>Reviews per page</h5>
        <select asp-items="@ViewBag.ProductCount" id="perPage" 
class="dropdown-button btn"></select>

    </form>

</div>
</div>


<p></p>
<div class="reviewView" id="filter">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("ShowReviewDetails", Model)
</div>
```

Child View:

```
    @model IPagedList<YaCu_2017.Models.Review>
@using System.Globalization
@using Sakura.AspNetCore

@using YaCu_2017.Controllers
@using YaCu_2017.Models
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Digital Jeeves - Reviews";


}
<form method="post" data-ajax="true">
<div class="row">
    <div id="pagerow" class="col s12 center center-align center-block">
        <p>Page @(Model.TotalPage < Model.PageIndex ? 1 :  
Model.PageIndex) of @Model.TotalPage<pager id="pager" class="pagination"  
setting-link-attr-data-ajax-update="filter" setting-link-attr-data-ajax-  
mode="replace" setting-link-attr-data-ajax="true" /></></p>
        <cs-pager cs-paging-pagesize="@Model.PageSize"
                  cs-paging-pagenumber="@Model.PageIndex"
                  cs-paging-totalitems="@Model.TotalPage"
                  cs-pagenumber-param="page"                      
                  asp-route-perPage="@ViewData["Page"]"
                  asp-route-searchProduct="@ViewData["Product"]"
                  asp-controller="Review"
                  asp-action="GetProducts"
                  cs-ajax-target="filter"></cs-pager>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<hr />
<div id="stuff">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    var stars = item.Stars.ToString();
    var starurl = string.Format("images/stars/{0}_star.jpg", stars);
    <div class="container opaque-parent z-depth-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s6"><h6 style="border-bottom:thin">Title :   
@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Title)</h6></div>
            <div class="col s3"><h6 style="border-bottom:thin">Product :  
@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Product)</h6></div>
            <div class="col s3"><h6 style="border-bottom:thin">Rated: 
<img src="~/@starurl" class="responsive-img" id="@item.Id" /></h6></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="">
            <div class="col s12" style="border-bottom:inset">
                <h6>Comment:</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="border-bottom:inset">
            <div class="col s6 offset-s3">
                <p class="flow-text">"@Html.DisplayFor(model =>
item.ReviewText)"</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s3">
                <p>Date Created : @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>   
item.CreatedDate)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col s3">
                <p>Chosen Display Name: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>      
item.DisplayName)</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
}
</div>
```

I thought that it may be because its a child trying to update a parent, but I cant find any info. I tried to put pagination outside of the target div, all that happend was the pagination never got updated when there were pages >1.

I'm new to this, only having made websites without ajax, until now! I figured the filter/sorting out, but I keep going around in circles here, I even tried a diferent nuget package for pagination [Link to git](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe.Web.Pagination), still no joy! Like I say, the next page is in the response, but it doesn't replace whats there.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... in the data-ajax-update="filter" I needed to add a hashtag infront of the element id e.g. data-ajax-update="#filter"... facepalm